# PHP_CodeSniffer PEAR.Commenting.FunctionComment.ParamNameNoMatch error

Tags: phpcodesniffer

My source code generates the following error with PHP_CodeSniffer.
"Doc comment for var &$myVar does not match actual variable name $myVar at position 2"

PEAR.Commenting.FunctionComment.ParamNameNoMatch

The code:

```
/**
* Function comment
*
* @param object $newVar some comment
* @param array &$myVar some comment
*
* @return null
*/
private function _myFunction($newVar, &$myVar) {
    // my code here...
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please follow the link for the fix: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/478

Answer (score 0):

PHPDoc does not support ampersands and PHP Codesniffer is strictly implementing PHPDoc.
I would prefer it to be considered a PHPDoc bug that needs addressed rather than a having Codesniffer conform.   How else do you document that a variable is passed by reference?!

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/248